# Difference between 設定する and 調整する

Tags: word-choice, words

Sorry, I don't have any example sentences... 
Anyway, usually I heard the word 設定{せってい} in the meaning of "adjusting something". But now, in the factory, I have come across the phrase "圧力{あつりょく}を調整{ちょうせい}する".
Could you please define the difference in usage between 設定{せってい}する and 調整{ちょうせい}する?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the difference can be summarised as:

- 設定 - to set or configure
- 調整 - to set or configure **towards a desired/expected outcome or value**

I think 設定 is to set it up so that it works, while 調整 has a goal in mind.

Looking up some online dictionaries:

[設定](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A-548363#E3.83.87.E3.82.B8.E3.82.BF.E3.83.AB.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.B3.89):

> - (ディジタル大辞泉) 
>   ある物事や条件をつくり定めること
> - (大辞林 第三版) 
>   ある目的に沿って，新たに物事をもうけ定めること

[調整](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E8%AA%BF%E6%95%B4-568677#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88):

> (大辞林 第三版)
>   1. 調子の悪いものに手を加えてととのえること
>   2. ある基準に合わせてととのえること。過不足なくすること。

設定 means to set up or establish according to some standard/condition that was decided.

調整 means to adjust it from a undesirable or bad state, back in order to a desired state. Or in the second explanation, to adjust something away from being too much or too little in order to conform with an established standard.

Comment: Note 調整 can mean "arrange a schedule" in business scenes.  Also, 設定 can mean settings as in "the story unfolds in XYZ settings."

Answer (score 5):

設定 often implies you start from *tabula rasa*.

調整 is more like optimization.